# Display AlertDialog after launching a webview using CustomTabsIntent

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog

I am using CustomTabsIntent to launch a url.
Is it possible to display a dialog after the url has been launched? Like a dialog inside that webview.

Because currently my dialog is displaying before the webview appears.

Tried adding the creation of dialog after launchUrl is called.
Also tried adding it in onNavigationEvent in CustomCallback but it seems that it's not being called.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }


        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPageStarted $url")
            openYourDiaogHere() //your dialog method 
        }

     }
```

Comment: https://mullr.dev/2020/06/08/258/ 

this link may helpful for you. Please check @Alertomiant